# Trying to loop through URLs and save contents, as a data frame, to text file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, url, pandas

I think this block of code is pretty close to being right, but something is throwing it off.  I'm trying to loop through 10 URLs and download the contents of each to a text file, and make sure everything is structured orderly, in a `dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd
rawHtml = ''
url = r'http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page=" + i + "&searchbox=Course%20Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0'
g = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/MyData.txt", "w")
for i in range(0, 10):      
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(url)
    print(df)
    g.write(str(df))
    g.close()
```

The error that I get says:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data.
C error: Expected 1 fields in line 22, saw 2
```

I have no idea what that means.  I only have 9 lines of code, so I don't know why it's mentioning a problem on line 22.

Can someone give me a push to get this working?

Comment: the line `df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(url)` is the one causing the error, the line 22 is in the webpage possibly because it is pointing to an html page instead of a csv...

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.DataFrame.from_csv()` takes a first argument which is either a path or a file-like handle, where either are supposed to be pointing at valid CSV file.

You are providing it with a URL.

It seems that you want to use a different function: the top-level [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv). This function will actually fetch the data from you from a valid URL, then parse it.

If for any reason you insist on using `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv()`, you will have to:

1. Get the text from the page.
2. Persist the text, or parts thereof, as a valid CSV file, or a file-like object.
3. Provide the path to the file, or the handler of the file-like, as the first argument to `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv()`.

Comment: providing a url to `from_csv` is completely valid, it will get the text from the page.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: I think you might be confusing `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv()` with `pandas.read_csv()`. The former (which OP is trying to use) will not fetch data from a URL; only the latter will. I will add this to my answer though.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what is happening.  There has to be a CSV within the URL, right.  Well, there isn't one.  Only names of golf courses, addresses, and web sites for each course.  I want to download those three items for the first 10 pages of URLs.

Comment: @ryguy7272: That begs the question of why you're trying to use a `from_csv()` in the first place, for data that isn't CSV.

Comment: @DunPeal, I think you are mistaken: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(r'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv')` works fine. (a result from googling "sample csv")

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Interesting! If you are using the latest stable release, that means the [official docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html)
 are lacking: "**path:** string file path or file handle / StringIO". Either way, seems like a moot point since OP just commented that the source data isn't CSV-formatted.

Comment: @ryguy7272: If the data isn't CSV, you sholdn't try to use the `read_csv()` methods to parse it. You will have to parse the page itself, and store the results in the `DataFrame`. Also, make sure you are not violating the source website ToS by doing this!

Comment: @DunPeal yes, `pd.__version__` is `'0.18.0'` which is same as docs but the source for `from_csv` just forwards a call to `pandas.io.parsers.read_table` and [the doc for that](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) does say it can take a URL

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working.  This is what I was trying to do all along.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page=1&searchbox=Course%20Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0"
html = requests.get(link).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
res = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "views-field-nothing"})
for r in res:
    print("Address: " + r.find("span", {'class': 'field-content'}).text)
```